# citrix receiver connection bar

Tags: windows, macos, citrix, receiver

I started a Citrix Published App on my IPad and get a citrix receiver toolbar which contains the Icons `home`, `Active keys`, ... `Pointer`, `Magnifier` on top of the screen.

On my Windows 10 tablet device, after setting `ConnectionBar=1` in ica file, I also get a toolbar, but it contains different Icons. It does not contain the icons `Pointer` and `Magnifier`, which I need. Some Icons are contained in both OS's, e.g. `home`.

--> Is there a general difference between Windows and Mac Citrix Receiver or can I set this Icons to be displayed anyhow?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

`Pointer` and `Magnifier` have been introduced  for the “[new](https://www.citrix.com/blogs/2012/03/16/citrix-receiver-and-the-new-ipad/)” iPad  to deal with higher resolution screens - so yes, they're specific gestures of Citrix Receiver for iOS, as per Citrix [documentation](http://support.citrix.com/help/receiver/58/ios/en/mobile-receiver-user-gestures-ios.html).

More generally speaking, in Windows 10 Magnifier is yet another of the Windows Ease of Access [features](http://www.howtogeek.com/223319/how-to-manage-accessibility-features-in-windows-10/) (whilst in Desktop *with a keyboard* you could quickly open it by using the keyboard shortcut Windows key with the plus sign (+) to zoom, as suggested in [windowscentral](http://www.windowscentral.com/how-use-magnifier-windows-10) and in [microsoft](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/use-magnifier) links, notice the "Use Magnifier with a *touchscreen*" paragraph in the latter).

In case of tablet and Citrix Receiver **for HTML5**, please refer to the recent Citrix [blog](https://www.citrix.com/blogs/2016/05/02/receiver-for-html5-2-0-now-supported-on-mobile-and-tablet/): this release adds support for mobile gestures and multi-touch. Now, you can **pinch and zoom**, etc...